# Cannot start Visual Studio 2012 performance analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

Always when i try to start the Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 performance analysis, a german Error Message pops up (my visual studio language is set to english but my OS language is German)

```
Starten nicht möglich: $Executable Path$ Die Profilerstellung 
konnte bei der angegebenen 
Konfiguration nicht mit dem Sampling beginnen.
```

My solution consists of 2 projects. A class library project and a WPF userinterface project.
I run Visual Studio as administrator but it doesn´t help at all. What can cause this error message?

**Update:**

i cant even analyze a simple ConsoleApplication. Always quits with the error message above or

```
Unbekannter Fehler
```

oder

```
Die Laufzeitbibliothek konnte nicht eingebunden werden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i reinstalled visual studio under windows 8 and now its working probably.